# Regex to find table rows in mediawiki - Python

Tags: python, regex, mediawiki, regex-group, wikipedia-api

I would like to define Regex expression that extracts each row in a mediawiki table of format as `text` (shown bellow). The rows in mediawiki are identified by `|-`. The problem is that I am skipping one element each time. I find the pattern but then miss one element in between.

Here is what I have so far:

```
text = '|-\n|[[Phantom Zone#Pre-Crisis|Xadu, Doctor]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Adventure Comics]], Vol. 1, #283\n|1961\n|April\n|[[Robert Bernstein (comics)|Robert Bernstein]]\n|[[George Papp]]\n|-\n|[[Empire (comics)#Characters|Xanna]]\n|\n|[[Gorilla Comics]]/[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Empire (comics)|Empire]], Vol. 1, #1\n|2000\n|May\n|[[Mark Waid]]\n|[[Barry Kitson]]\n|-\n|[[Sparta of Synriannaq#Character history|Xanthi]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Teen Titans#The New Teen Titans (1980–1996)|New Titans]], Vol. 1, #51\n|1989\n|January\n|[[Marv Wolfman]] and [[George Pérez]]\n|[[George Pérez]]\n|-\n|[[Xardo (Action Comics 325)|Xardo]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Action Comics]], Vol. 1, #325\n|1965\n|June\n|\n|[[Curt Swan]]\n|-\n|[[Xasnu (Action Comics 278)|Xasnu]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Action Comics]], Vol. 1, #278\n|1961\n|July\n|[[Jerry Coleman (comics)|Jerry Coleman]]\n|[[Curt Swan]]\n'

ROWS = re.findall(r"\|\-(.*?)\|\-", text, re.S)
```

With this I get a list of two elements:

```
>> ROWS
['\n|[[Phantom Zone#Pre-Crisis|Xadu, Doctor]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Adventure Comics]], Vol. 1, #283\n|1961\n|April\n|[[Robert Bernstein (comics)|Robert Bernstein]]\n|[[George Papp]]\n',
 '\n|[[Sparta of Synriannaq#Character history|Xanthi]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Teen Titans#The New Teen Titans (1980–1996)|New Titans]], Vol. 1, #51\n|1989\n|January\n|[[Marv Wolfman]] and [[George Pérez]]\n|[[George Pérez]]\n']
```

But in fact I should have three rows detected:

```
>> ROWS
['\n|[[Phantom Zone#Pre-Crisis|Xadu, Doctor]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Adventure Comics]], Vol. 1, #283\n|1961\n|April\n|[[Robert Bernstein (comics)|Robert Bernstein]]\n|[[George Papp]]\n',
'\n|[[Empire (comics)#Characters|Xanna]]\n|\n|[[Gorilla Comics]]/[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Empire (comics)|Empire]], Vol. 1, #1\n|2000\n|May\n|[[Mark Waid]]\n|[[Barry Kitson]]\n',
 '\n|[[Sparta of Synriannaq#Character history|Xanthi]]\n|\n|[[DC Comics]]\n|[[Teen Titans#The New Teen Titans (1980–1996)|New Titans]], Vol. 1, #51\n|1989\n|January\n|[[Marv Wolfman]] and [[George Pérez]]\n|[[George Pérez]]\n']
```

Comment: please update the expected output

Comment: hi @Ramesh, is it clearer now?

Comment: Use `re.findall(r"\|-(.*?)(?=\|-)", text, re.S)` or  `re.findall(r"\|-(.*?)(?=\|-|\z)", text, re.S)`

Comment: `ROWS = re.split(r"\|\-\s", text)` https://trinket.io/python3/3b2637b08d